# String Manipulation - Remove End Characters

Tags: java, string

I have a incoming string as below.

`Sample ("Testing")`

I need to replace  the substring `("Testing")` with `"Testing"`. 
Basically i need to remove the left and right paranthesis.

Please provide me pointers to do the same in java.

Comment: Very easy. What did you try?

Comment: I'd start by reading the String class javadoc - google is your friend!

Comment: Substring it out I don't really see what you want otherwise.

Comment: Need to remove left and right parenthesis only when there is string ("Testing"). for example the string is as follows. Test(Text == Text, Id==id) from entry-point ("Testing"). In the above string i need to remove paranthesis only when the string Testing is surrounded by paranthesis.In the rest of the senarios i should not remove the paranthesis.

Answer (score 2):

The unnecessary regex checking approach:

```
String newstring = sample.replaceAll("\\(", "");
newstring = newstring.replaceAll("\\)", "");
System.out.println(newstring);
```

The better approach(no regex check, direct substring checking):

```
String newstring = sample.replace("(", "");
newstring = newstring.replace(")", "");
System.out.println(newstring);
```

Another approach using substring method:

```
 String newstring=sample.substring(0,sample.indexOf('('))+sample.substring(sample.indexOf('(')+1,sample.lastIndexOf(')'));
```

**EDIT:**
To remove parenthesis only when there is "Testing" within parenthesis, follow the below code:

```
String newstring = sample.replace("(\"Testing\")","\"Testing\"");
```

The regex checking way:

```
String newstring=sample.replaceAll("(\\()(?=(\"Testing\"))","");
newstring = newstring.replaceAll("(?<=(\"Testing\"))\\)","");
```

But common sense says that you should do it this way:

```
if(sample.equals("Sample (\"Testing\")")
sample="Sample \"Testing\"";
```

Comment: Need to remove left and right parenthesis only when there is string ("Testing"). for example the string is as follows.                                                                   Test(Text == Text, Id==id)  from entry-point ("Testing").                                                             In the above string i need to remove paranthesis only when the string Testing is surrounded by paranthesis.In the rest of the senarios i should not remove the paranthesis.

Comment: see the edit for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this short tutorial that tells you about the replace function :

[Java String Replace Example Tutorial](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ro/2011/12/java-string-replace-example-tutorial.html)